# Override Nivo Slider style nivo-control with Jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, nivo-slider

I am using the Nivo plugin in Wordpress. What I would like to do is use jQuery to apply a dynamic thumbnail width based on the number of images in the carousel. The problem I am having is the jQuery script is not being respected. I think the Slider plugin script is loading after I am calling my script, so it is never really getting executed.

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Nivo Pagination
    var imageCount = jQuery(".nivoSlider").children().length;
    var nivoEntry = 824 / imageCount;
    jQuery(".nivo-control").css("width",nivoEntry);
});
</script>
```

When debugging, I have tried to apply different css styles to different selectors in the .nivoSlider class with no luck. That's why I think it is a delegation issue. I even tried to enqueue the script in the functions to force just this snippet to load last with no luck. Is there a way to force this into the .nivo-control class?

Comment: Perhaps you could run your code as an `afterLoad` function?

Comment: You mean from the Nivoslider call? Since it is a WP plugin, I never have to insert the script that calls Nivo (ie $(".nivoslider").slider {). If you are referring to something else, please explain.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, if there is no way to set the `afterLoad` option in the Wordpress plugin, then you can't use my suggestion.

Comment: Can jQuery listen for a specific call? That would be ideal.

Comment: Only if the slider triggered an event. This is a timing issue, so perhaps you could use a delay or polling?